# Picker is springing back when I use an EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI

Tags: environment-variables, swiftui, picker

I have created a quiet simple Picker and want to use an EnvironmentObject as datasource, but always when I use it, the Picker is springing back to default.

```
class HobbiesOfUser: ObservableObject {
@Published var hobbies = ["Swimming", "Football", "Hockey", "Rugby", "Other"]}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var hobbiesOfUser: HobbiesOfUser
//   @State var hobbiesOfUser = ["Swimming", "Football", "Hockey", "Rugby", "Other"]

    var body: some View {
                            Picker(selection: $hobbiesOfUser.hobbies, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< hobbiesOfUser.hobbies.count) {
                                Text(self.hobbiesOfUser.hobbies[$0]).tag($0)
                            }.labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to choose another form of Picker, but it has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Selection should be one item of array, not the complete array, as below

```
@EnvironmentObject var hobbiesOfUser: HobbiesOfUser

@State private var selected = "Swimming"
var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< hobbiesOfUser.hobbies.count) {
            Text(self.hobbiesOfUser.hobbies[$0]).tag($0)
        }.labelsHidden()
    }
}
```